With openpyxl, how could I remove rows as well as their filling colors?
In a .xlsx file, only its cells A1:B3 have data, and row 1 to 3 are filled with color. See the figure below:
The original rows filled with color
With the following code I can remove row 1 to 3:
    src_fname_path = "./test_delete_row.xlsx"
    new_fname_path = "./test_delete_row.delete.xlsx"
    src_book = openpyxl.load_workbook (src_fname_path)
    sheet = src_book ['Sheet1']
    sheet.delete_rows (1, 3)
    src_book.save (new_fname_path)

However, the colors filling row 1 to 3 remain unchanged, like the figure below:
The row with data are deleted but their filling colors still remain
How can I remove row 1 to 3 as well as their filling colors?

Hi Moken,
OK, I see. Anyway, you've given me a direction so I know what to try next.
Thanks for you kind help and comment!

Refer to this post where the complete row is filled. Using an Excel module Xlwings or Win32com will delete the rows if using Windows and these modules can be used.
